# Application crashed while change password with Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

my application crashed after trying to change password with Firebase.
The whole application was fine until I added these code:

```
btnChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(mUser != null) {
                AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, oldPass);

                newPass = edt_newPass.getText().toString().trim();

                mUser.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            mUser.updatePassword(newPass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Password Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    } else {

                                        String errorMsg = task.getException().getMessage();

                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR Occurred: " + errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }

                                }
                            });

                        } else {

                            String errorMsg = task.getException().getMessage();

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR Occurred: " + errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
```

Here is the error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.user.expensesmanagment, PID: 10032
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
                  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.zzgm(Unknown Source:10)
                  at com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown Source:3)
                  at com.example.user.expensesmanagment.ChangePasswordFragment$1.onClick(ChangePasswordFragment.java:59)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
                  at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
                  at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

ChangePasswordFragment.java:59 is this line of code:

```
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, oldPass);
```

FYI, I am logged in. So, the E-mail shouldn't be null. I also typed in both the old password and new password, so it shouldn't be null too.. Or maybe there's something wrong with my code. I also imported these:

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
```

Any idea what's going on?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

This is the code about how I get the old password, new password, and email:

```
       edt_oldPass = myview.findViewById(R.id.old_password);
    edt_newPass = myview.findViewById(R.id.new_password);
    btnChange = myview.findViewById(R.id.btn_change);


    //Firebase
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    final String email = mUser.getEmail();
    oldPass = edt_oldPass.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: Share you whole class code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add null check before using the values **email** and **oldPass** as below -

```
btnChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(mUser != null) {
           if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(oldPass) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, 
oldPass);

            newPass = edt_newPass.getText().toString().trim();

            mUser.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new 
 OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        mUser.updatePassword(newPass).addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Password Changed", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                } else {

                                    String errorMsg = 
task.getException().getMessage();

                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR Occurred: " + 
errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }

                            }
                        });
                      }
                    
                    } else {

                        String errorMsg = task.getException().getMessage();

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR Occurred: " + errorMsg, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong...", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for helping. This solved my problem. Also, I accidentally updated your answer instead of my post. Please ignore the update. 

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: No issues, Kindly upvote the answer if you found it useful. Thanks.

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. However, I marked your answer as my solution. ;)

Comment: Oh, You can only upvote after 15 reputations. No issues. Thanks